# Captcha Code in JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a validation Form using Javascript. It must validate the name, email and captcha. But through my validation function, the name and email are validated but the captcha is not validated after the `onclick` of the submit button.

The following functions shows my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateform(){   
var cm_name=document.supportus_form.cm_name.value;  
var cm_email=document.supportus_form.cm_email.value;
var atpos = cm_email.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = cm_email.lastIndexOf(".");


if (cm_name==null || cm_name=="")
{  
  alert("Name can't be blank");  
  return false; 
}
else if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) 
{ 
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
}
 var why = "";

if(theform.CaptchaInput.value == ""){
why += "- Please Enter CAPTCHA Code.\n";
}
if(theform.CaptchaInput.value != ""){
if(ValidCaptcha(theform.CaptchaInput.value) == false){
why += "- The CAPTCHA Code Does Not Match.\n";
}
}
if(why != ""){
alert(why);
return false;
}
}

var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';

var code = a + b + c + d + e;
document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
document.getElementById("CaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;

// Validate input against the generated number
function ValidCaptcha(){
var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('CaptchaInput').value);
if (str1 == str2){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
} </script>
```

The following is my html code for the form which i am using:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action='<?php echo
site_url(); ?>/Welcome/insert_support_info' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateform()" name="supportus_form">
                        <br style="clear:both"/>
                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;"><u>Let us Know your Interest</u></h3>
                               <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cm_name" id="fullname" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cm_email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your E-Mail"/>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cm_phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number or Mobile Number"/>


                                <textarea class="form-control" name="cm_message" id="message" rows="3" placeholder="Add your Query"></textarea>
                                <span class="help-block"><p id="characterLeft" class="help-block ">Limit - 100 words</p></span>
                                <input class="form-control" name="datetime" value="<?php
                                    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
                                    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()); echo $date;
                                ?>" type="hidden" />
                                <!-- START CAPTCHA -->
<br>
<div class="capbox">

<div id="CaptchaDiv"></div>

<div class="capbox-inner">
Type the above number:<br>

<input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha">
<input type="text" name="CaptchaInput" id="CaptchaInput" size="15"><br>

</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<!-- END CAPTCHA -->

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </div>
                                <hr/>

                        </form>
```

I have kept the css to show up the captcha form

```
<style>
   .capbox {
    background-color: #92D433;
    border: #B3E272 0px solid;
    border-width: 0px 12px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; zoom: 1; /* FOR IE7-8 */
    padding: 8px 40px 8px 8px;
    }

.capbox-inner {
    font: bold 11px arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #DBF3BA;
    margin: 5px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    }

#CaptchaDiv {
    font: bold 17px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    }

#CaptchaInput { margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px; width: 135px; }

   </style>
```

With the Above code, the captcha is not working. I am using captcha for the first time.

Comment: Do you realise that anyone (including a spam bot) can just cheat on the captcha by looking at the source of the page and seeing what is in the txtCaptcha hidden field? A better solution might be to use an established captcha solution such as Google's ReCaptcha which does the validation securely on a remote server.

Comment: @ADyson, Kindly guide me to do that. how to do Google's ReCaptcha? I am new to this..

Comment: you can follow the guidance on their site: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/ is the general intro, and https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/ contains the guidance for developers. It is free to use. If you implement it and can't make it work as a question here with your code.

Comment: @ADyson, I have followed it, and i kept the Google's ReCaptcha to my Form, it is a lot easier. Thanks for saving me from cheaters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey You are using conditional tags in improper way . That leads to unknown bugs. Following Javascript code works you correct.

```
function validateform(){   
    var cm_name=document.supportus_form.cm_name.value;
    var cm_email=document.supportus_form.cm_email.value;
    var atpos = cm_email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = cm_email.lastIndexOf(".");
    var captha = document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value;
    var capthaValue =   document.getElementById('CaptchaInput').value.replace(/ /g,'');
    console.log(typeof captha);
    if(capthaValue == "" || captha != capthaValue) {
        validCaptcha()
    }

    if (cm_name==null || cm_name=="")
    {  
      alert("Name can't be blank");  
      return false; 
    }
    else if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) 
    { 
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      return false;
    }
    function validCaptcha() {
        var why = "";
        if(capthaValue == ""){
            why += "- Please Enter CAPTCHA Code.\n";
        }
        if(capthaValue != ""){
            if((captha != capthaValue) == false){
                why += "- The CAPTCHA Code Does Not Match.\n";
            }
        }
        if(why != ""){
        alert(why);
        return false;
        }
    }
}

var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';

var code = a + b + c + d + e;
document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
document.getElementById("CaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;
```

Comment: oh you are a little bit late, but any how i will test with this code above..!

Comment: @VijayKumarB This may fix the code but I'd like to note for future readers that it doesn't alter the fact that the design is fundamentally flawed. This is because the answer to the captcha is contained within the page's source itself, making it insecure and the result unable to be trusted. Also, any entirely-client-side validation cannot be trusted at all because a malicious user could simply alter the code (using the developer tools) to bypass the check, and a bot could bypass the script entirely and submit the form directly. Server-side validation of _all_ data  should always be done as well

Comment: @Keynes Ok fine